# Using Bcrypt in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bcrypt

I am doing a local login and right know my password is stored on an h2 databse in plain text.

I want to use the `Bcrypt` in spring but I get this error on my application launch:

```
Field bCryptPasswordEncoder in com.alert.interservices.uaa.Bootstrap required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' that could not be found.
```

To use `Bcrypt` I only Autowired it in my controller and encrypt the password.
I did the same on my Bootstrap when filling the database:

Controller:

```
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

/**
 * 
 * @param user the user that is trying to access
 * @return the user if it is successfull or a bad request if not
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public Object authenticate(@RequestBody UserEntity user) {

    logger.debug("Begin request UAAController.authenticate()");

    String encriptedPasswd=bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword().getPassword());

    UserEntity usr = authenticationService.authenticate(user.getName(), encriptedPasswd);

    (...)
```

Bootstrap:

```
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@GetMapping("/test")
public void fillDatabse() {


    String encodedPw=bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("test");
    Password p = new Password(encodedPw);
```

What Im I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`BCryptPasswordEncoder` is not a bean, you can not autowire it.

use:

```
Password p = new Password(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(encodedPw));
```

instead of

```
String encodedPw=bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("test");
Password p = new Password(encodedPw);
```

and remove

```
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
```

Also make these changes in your controller

Comment: Alternatively he could create such bean in his configuration :)

Comment: Thanks for helping me guys!! One more question, to see if the users exists i nthe databse I have to decrypt the password? @Jens

Comment: Typically when you register your user, you should keep the hash of his password. When user tries to log in, you hash the password, that he entered, and you compare the hashes. You should never keep passwords in plain text in your db for security reasons.

Comment: @michalk sir I am stuck at the point to validate the user.
Please have a look to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60284709/decrypting-the-data-of-column-stored-using-columntransfer-annotation

Answer (score 6):

You can provide a bean of `BCryptPasswordEncoder` by putting the following code in any of your package scanned classes annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, `@Configuration`...

```
@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Also, notice that the method signature could have been

`public PasswordEncoder myPasswordEncoder()` (and the rest is the same)

[See an example in a working project](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/gms/Application.java#L85).

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can provide a bean in @SpringBootApplication or any of the class like this

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

then in the service you can autowire the Bcript and use like the below example

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public Users createUser(@RequestBody Users userEntity) {    
    userEntity.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userEntity.getPassword()));
    return userRepo.save(userEntity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from the way you attempt to inject the password encoder (evident from the error message you're getting).

You cannot simply attempt to inject an implementation of the `PasswordEncoder` interface, in this case `BCryptPasswordEncoder` this way. If you want to have it readily available and in Spring context (thus available for injection whenever needed) you need to follow a different approach.

Instantiate a bean manually somewhere and bring it into context using the `bean` annotation. Then inject it whenever needed. A simple example you be the following:

1) Create a service named `PasswordService` like so:

```
@Service
public final class PasswordService {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

As mentioned above this will bring an instance of the password encoder into context.

Then use it this way whenever needed:

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder
```

You'll effectively avoid instantiating the encoder each time manually.

Comment: Read https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html about differences declaring `@Bean` in @Configuration` and `@Component` annotated classes

Comment: Annotating the method with `@bean` in a service class does effectively mean that this will not work. In this case the created bean in question would a lite bean. Since there are no calls to other bean annotated methods, using this way to create it is not entirely wrong since there are no inter-bean relations. Spring 5 docs mention this: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts